# Changing the text in a label from a function

Tags: json, swift, uiviewcontroller, uilabel, ios8.1

I have a function that has requested data from a JSON communication.

```
let title:NSString = jsonData.objectForKey("title") as NSString
```

now that I have a variable with the title. I want to now set it to the label that I have on a view.

This is linked to my document

```
@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
```

so my final step I think should be:

```
self.titleLabel.text = "\(title)"
```

Sadly this does not work and I get the following error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb) 

Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_i386_INVOP, subcode=0x0
```

I used NSlog to output to check if the variable title is nil, and I found that its populated:

```
[3426:83507] Using email accounts over POP on Windows 8.1
```

Any help as I'm stuck on this.

```
import Foundation
```

import UIKit

```
class SolutionViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var searchTerm: UITextField!

@IBAction func searchTapped(){

    var searchTerms:NSString = searchTerm.text

    if ( searchTerms.isEqualToString("") ) {

        var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
        alertView.title = "Empty Search Term"
        alertView.message = "Please enter a search term"
        alertView.delegate = self
        alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
        alertView.show()
    } else {
        let strSearchTerm:String = "\(searchTerms)"
        var convSearchTerm:String = strSearchTerm.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "+", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)

        var post:NSString = "searchTerm=\(convSearchTerm)"

        NSLog("PostData: %@",post);

        var url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://turbo-tires-21-188007.euw1.nitrousbox.com/iosSearch.php?searchTerm=\(convSearchTerm)")!

        var postData:NSData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!

        var postLength:NSString = String( postData.length )

        var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.HTTPBody = postData
        request.setValue(postLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")


        var reponseError: NSError?
        var response: NSURLResponse?

        var urlData: NSData? = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error:&reponseError)

        if ( urlData != nil ) {
            let res = response as NSHTTPURLResponse!;

            NSLog("Response code: %ld", res.statusCode);

            if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode < 300)
            {
                var responseData:NSString  = NSString(data:urlData!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

                NSLog("Response ==> %@", responseData);

                var error: NSError?

                let jsonData:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers , error: &error) as NSDictionary


                let title:NSString? = jsonData.objectForKey("title") as? NSString

                NSLog("\(title)")
                if title != "" {

                self.titleLabel.text = "\(title)"
                //[jsonData[@"success"] integerValue];
                }


            }
        }
    }
};
}
```

Comment: any able help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring your title variable as optional by doing:

```
var title:NSString? = jsonData.objectForKey("title") as? NSString
```

If nil is shown on label then object for key title not exist or cant be cast to NSString. After doing this if the error occurs again it means that your titleLabel is nil and its time to check the referencing outlet of your label in connection inspector of storyboard if it exist or not[image]

Comment: Your dead right but that was a typo from me, thanks.

Comment: thanks for your reply! I tried that and no change in error. Still crashing.

Comment: Have you checked if titleLabel is connected properly ? If yes then post the full code because error its not here

Comment: while testing self.titleLabel.text = "test" does not work but as you can see above, i already linked it

Comment: Check the link again by clicking on label and connection inspector like in screenshot above

Comment: Can you try putting self.titleLabel.text = "test on viewDidLoad method and remove from everywhere else ?

Comment: I did and it crashes the app on load. I am guessing it has something to do with the label and the script.

Comment: Try removing referencing outlet delete `@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!` then create reference again

Comment: So what I did was, i have a new file called SolutionViewController.swift and in the UIview Controller in the storyboard I set the class as Solution View Controller. Then I Select Dragged a button from that to another page, I did the same with setting the class above. I then Click Dragged this the button to the action function as well as the label as a class variable.

From the infromation I gathered from the textfield on the first page I do a http request, get data back and then when I try set it to a label, everything breaks.

Comment: self.titlesLabel.text = "test" I did and nothing changed